# Find the formula of a sequence using generating functions

Tags: generating-functions

The given sequence is $\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k}$.

How can I do this? I think I should start with the already known generating function:

$A(x) = \sum a^{n}x^{n} = \frac{1}{1 - ax}$

And then I should do something with this function so that I finally come up with the given one. But well, how can I do this?

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}kx^{k} = \sum_{k>=1} [A(x) - 1]k$

I could only get something like this, but first of all it's not the formula without sums, and second I'm not sure it's correct.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x^{k}}{\mathrm{d}x}=kx^{k-1}$$

and$$\dfrac{d(\dfrac{1}{1-x})}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}$$

So when $n\rightarrow \infty$,$$1+x+x^{2}+\cdots=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$$
On differentiating,
$$1+2x+3x^{2}+\cdots=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}$$
Multiply with $x$,
$$x+2x^{2}+3x^{3}+\cdots=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^{2}}$$

Comment: So simple, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

An idea without (properly) generating functions:

$$\forall\,|x|<1\;,\;\;\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\stackrel{\text{derivative}}\implies\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}\;\;\ldots$$

Comment: $kx^{k-1}$ inside the final sum? Or $x$ in the numerator on the left of that?

Comment: Good catch, @HaraldHanche-Olsen . Thanks.

Comment: And an extra hint to the OP: It seems you only want the partial sum of this, up to the $n$th term. But you can just as easily play the above game with finite sums.