# Creating a formula for calculating $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac k{(1+r)^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can anyone help to find a formula for this?

> $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(1+r)^k}=\frac{1}{1+r}+\frac{2}{(1+r)^2}+\frac{3}{(1+r)^3}+\cdots+\frac{n}{(1+r)^n}.$$

I cannot seem to use $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ in anyway.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please be careful in te choice of your tags. This problem isn't about the `cauchy-integral-formula`.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388349/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180198/42969

Comment: Note that your sum can be written as $\sum_{k=1}^n k x^k$ with $x = \frac{1}{1+r}$.